# Rally API defect query returning inaccurate results

Tags: rally, rallyapi, agile-central-api

I'm using Rally API v2.0 to access a list of defects. The criteria is to get all `Submitted`, `Open`, or `Fixed` defects from a specific project. While I am able to get a pretty large list, I don't get every defect. For example I notice there are some defects that are marked as `Fixed` but also in an `Accepted` Schedule State. These defects are not returned. I see defects with every other schedule state (Idea, Defined, In-Progress, Released) but not Accepted.

Am I missing something or is this a potential issue?

```js
const query = "(((State%20%3D%20%22Submitted%22)%20OR%20(State%20%3D%20%22Open%22))%20OR%20(State%20%3D%20%22Open%22))";
const _fetch = "Applications,CreationDate,Description,FormattedID,Iteration,LastUpdateDate,Name,ObjectID,Owner,PlanEstimate,Project,ScheduleState,Severity,State";
const start = 1;
const pagesize = 2000;
const project = "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/project/<my_actual_project_id>";

// Set header
const headersMeta = {'ZSESSIONID': this.apiKey};
const options = {
    headers: headersMeta
};

// Build the url
const url = "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/defect?query=" + query +
    "&fetch=" + _fetch +
    "&start=" + start +
    "&pagesize=" + pagesize +
    "&project=" + project;

fetch(url, options) // more code to handle the response. No issues here.
```

Again, I do receive a response with `Open, Submitted, or Fixed` defects from my project. I am **not** getting any in a `Schedule State` of `Accepted`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I goofed. My query searches for `Open` twice and never checked for `Fixed`. Problem solved.

Leaving the post as an example of running a Rally API call.

Fixed line:

```js
const query = "(((State = %22Submitted%22) OR (State = %22Open%22)) OR (State = %22Fixed%22))";
```